# what is the best approach to scheduling repaint for winapi window?

Tags: winapi, gdi

I already tried multiple ways of rendering simple animations on winapi windows using wingdi, and realized that its fairly slow even for primitive animations, and inconsistent if i do it by spamming `SendMessageW` when there are no events for this window. So I thought that instead of rendering when I can i should schedule it with a fixed interval hence improving framerate and quality of the animation. I now wondering if this can be done with registering some callback with windows or there is no such functionality and i do have to spin another thread to function as a timer? Is it generally a better idea? What is the commonly accepted way to do things like this, when event triggered redraws just wont cut it?

Comment: Windows' GDI isn't the best option for smooth animations. You're probably better off using [Direct2D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-portal) and [DirectComposition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directcomp/directcomposition-portal). The latter, in particular, comes with a very flexible animation framework. If you are wondering how to use Direct2D from Rust, Kenny Kerr has put together a [great sample](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-samples-rs/tree/master/direct2d) to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the scheduled animations, there is `SetTimer()` and `KillTimer()`, if I remember their names correctly. In any case, "timer" is what you're looking for.

Concerning the painting in the timer callbacks, don't. Instead, adjust animation parameters (positions, colours etc) and trigger a redraw using `InvalidateRect()`. This will in turn invoke the regular drawing event handler. The difference is that this will not waste any CPU if your window is hidden or minimized. Also, in any case, when the window is un-hidden, the drawing event handler has to be able to draw the right window content anyway.

There is a derived version of this where you update an image in a memory DC and only blit to the window in the drawing event handler. It's unclear whether that is necessary in your case though. It's only when drawing takes an extended amount of time and you want to keep your UI responsive.

Comment: In my case my window is always on top and transparent as well as has its background brush as its 0 alpha colorkey. Essentially just making an overlay to render some cats cuz i love cats. I do use double buffering, but what do you mean by adjust animation? Unless it refers to adjusting the application state, i dont understand it? Do you mean there is a way to trigger partial redraws? Will it work with bitmaps? because right now, i first color my memdc with white, then gditransparentblit the bitmap and then bitblt memdc on normal dc

Comment: When you move a window over another so it is hidden halfway and then move it back, only the part that was hidden is redrawn. Things like line-drawing operations outside of the invalidated rect are simply skipped. Concerning the "adjust animation", I meant for example the position of a moving object. You only update the position in the timer event and trigger a redraw.

Comment: `WM_TIMER` messages are a common solution to the stated problem. You just need to be aware that `WM_TIMER` messages are low-priority messages. Even with a timeout of zero, it's easy to starve repaint request simply by rapidly moving the mouse across the window. `WM_MOUSEMOVE` events are also low-priority, but as long as the mouse did move, a program will not observe any `WM_TIMER` messages.

Comment: @IInspectable my window does not take any input because of the window style being transparent so i assume im fine on this one. I plan to subscribe to mouse hook because i would need to only capture mouse if its clicked to make cats draggable. Will it still starve the repaint?

Comment: I'm not aware of a window style that would prevent your window from receiving `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages. If there is, you'd still get into the very same situation if anyone would constantly post messages to your window. `WM_TIMER` is a low-priority message, and it's generated only if there aren't any higher-priority messages in the message queue. Any input has higher priority.

Comment: Given your *specific* use case, make sure to read [Windows with C++ : High-Performance Window Layering Using the Windows Composition Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/windows-with-c-high-performance-window-layering-using-the-windows-composition-engine). The code is rendering a circle, but I'm sure it will work for cat images just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well as my luck usually goes i found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/drawing-at-timed-intervals#:%7E:text=You%20can%20draw%20at%20timed%20intervals%20by%20creating,the%20client%20area%20while%20other%20applications%20continue%20running.) on MSDN, and it has a very nice example. Putting it here if someone will have same question